# How old was Ahaziah when he began to rule over Jerusalem?

Tags: contradiction, textual-criticism, kjv, 2-kings, 2-chronicles

How old was Ahaziah when he began to rule over Jerusalem?

**Answer1**

> 2 Kings 8:26 (KJV): Two and twenty years old

**Answer2**

> 2 Chronicles 22:2 (KJV): Forty and two years old

Comment: since you're interested in contradictions between chronicles and kings in general, this article might shed some light on this age old problem https://bible.org/article/reliability-kings-and-chronicles

Comment: @Bach, I need the answer to the titled question

Comment: *my question is closed [here](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47466)* - All Q&A sites on this particular domain have a strict policy of not allowing more than one (main) question per post.

Comment: Both? Perhaps he reigned twice.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer to the question is: Ahaziah was 22 years old when he began to reign according to 2 Kings 8:26.

The Hebrew text has been corrupted in 2 Chron 22:2 by recording "42 years old" - this can be deduced from several lines of evidence:

- The text of 2 Kings 8:26 differs
- Ahaziah's father was only 40 years old when he died (2 Chron 21:5, 20) making his son's age of 42 at the beginning of his reign impossible
- As listed in the footnotes of the NIV to 2 Chron 22:2, the Syriac say "22 years old", while the LXX has "20 years old".

Just why the Leningrad Codex (and thus the BHS) is corrupt at this point is unknown, perhaps by a copyist or transcriber.  Many modern versions recognise this (eg, NIV, NLT, ESV, NASB, CSB, CEV, ISV, HCSB, etc) and make the obvious correction.

Comment: Ok, nice then the Chronicles version should be through out since   2 Chronicles 22:2  claimed the wrong answer ?

Comment: Does all those [contradictions](https://www.islamawareness.net/Christianity/bible_contra_101.html?fbclid=IwAR1e4WD_9kCh3E89X7QJItwfGBU8SY0f6lpgEndvC9alptd77ACKJGGQ5kY) corrupted by by a copyist or transcriber ?

Comment: No - a very few are corruptions.  Some are due to other things such as … let us answer those individually.

Comment: what logic you have , Are 101 contradictions =very few in your mind ? you should know an epsilon contradiction in  any holybooks yield them  to be non word of God , God never come up with mistakes ? are you understanding ?

Comment: The Word of God is certain and pure.  Some copyist have made errors in transmitting the text - that is not a problem for the original text.  Not all the 101 errors you point out are due to corruptions - many are due to other features of the text that show that they are not contradictions at all.

Comment: if you are sure all of them not contradictions just to build me such PDF and answer all of them using convincing arguments , and before that try to check every contradiction using your Bible, am willing to provide you a prize of millions dollors if those contradictions are just text copyies error

Comment: On this site we can only deal with one question at a time. as has already been explained.

Comment: I think the titled question is one question not 101 question !! right

Comment: I have answered your titled question above.  But each of the other 101 questions has a different answer.

Comment: have you read my above comment ?

Comment: There are in fact other potential answers to this question, without resorting to 'textual corruption'. The 42 year number is probably a total calculated from a series of numbers, namely, the reigns of Ahab, Jeroham of Israel, and Jeroham of Judah respectively. The phrase in Hebrew is "a son of forty two years"(e.g. of Ahabic rule).

Comment: @user21676 - except that it was only 33 years since Ahab took the throne, AND, Ahaziah was not king of the northern kingdom (as Ahab was) but the southern Judean kingdom.

Comment: His mother, and also her father is the issue here, and why the number is attributed to Ahab(also cf. 2Ki 9:8a).